# Member to Member donations

Tags: civimember, developer, pledges, civipledge

1. can a Programmer customize CiviCRM to do

Member to Member donations with TRACKING of all the members and donations ?

2. what programming LANGUAGE is civicrm written in ?

Comment: Thanks for submitting your first question (or questions, more properly). You'll generally get better responses by submitting separate questions rather than two in one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean members donating TO other members or donations to be credited to other members?

You may be able to utilize the built in personal campaign pages for the first question, then your accountant/bookkeeper would write a check. The latter item is accomplished by the Soft Credit feature.

PHP is the primary language, although javascript, jquery, and ajax are some of the code families used in CiviCRM.